# Получить/назначить ID для компонента tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Только начал изучать tkinter для питона. Сам перехожу с фреймворков Js. Так вот вопрос, можно ли в назначить ID компоненту и в дальнейшем его вызвать.

```
# main.py
from gui import *

def main():
    tk = Tk()
    tk.geometry("800x450+500+300")
    tk.resizable(False, False)
    app = Engine(tk)
    tk.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# gui.py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox

class Engine(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Simple")
        self.place(x=0, y=0, width=800, height=450)

        btn_open_file = Button(self,  # родительское окно
                           text="Open File",  # надпись на кнопке
                           width=20, height=2,  # ширина и высота
                           bg="white", fg="black")  # цвет фона и надписи
        btn_open_file.bind("<Button>", self.OpenFile)  # при нажатии ЛКМ на кнопку вызывается функция OpenFile

        text_box = Text()

        # placing
        text_box.place(x=20, y=10, height=400, width=600)
        btn_open_file.place(x=630, y=10)

    def OpenFile(self, _pass_this_):
        file_diag = filedialog
        file_path = file_diag.askopenfilename()
        # print(file_path) =>>>>>>> text_box.insert(file_path)
```

В данном случае я хочу, в функции OpenFile записать file_path в виджет text_box, но не понимаю, как вызвать text_box в области видимости OpenFile

пробовал данный вариант.

```
btn_open_file = Button(...code..., name="MyTag")
catch_id = self.nametowidget(".MyTag")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\dev\PycharmProjects\test\gui.py", line 80, in SaveFile
    w = self.nametowidget(".da")
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1353, in nametowidget
    w = w.children[n]
KeyError: 'MyTag'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30005893/4794368

Comment: @qwabra, это я уже пробовал. второй кусок кода ниже

Comment: не похоже `.foo.b1`

Comment: @AntonGult, вы что-то не так делаете, у меня работает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGEO3.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Минимальный пример:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

b = Button(root, name='b1')
print(repr(b))  # Выводит <tkinter.Button object .b1> - т.е. имя фактически .b1
print(repr(root.nametowidget('.b1')))  # Выводит <tkinter.Button object .b1>
```

Т.е. с помощью `root.nametowidget('.b1')` получили объект по его текстовому имени.